# Cannot find module '@nestjs/mapped-types' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: docker, nestjs, nest

**Cannot find module '@nestjs/mapped-types' or its corresponding type declarations.**

I've tried

```
npm i @nestjs/mapped-types
```

```
yarn add @nestjs/mapped-types
```

```
yarn add @nestjs/swagger
```

these commands.

It works fine my localhost:3000 with **npm run start** command.
But, When i starting nestjs by docker, this error appeared.

**Here is my Dockerfile.**

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /var/www/nest

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

[here is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QtT0.png)

Comment: I'm not sure by try switching places between `COPY . .` and `RUN npm install`. It may be the case that you're overriding node_modules directory.

Comment: Why only `package.json` without lock?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.